# Sorting an array of version numbers in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Given an array of version numbers like this:

```
vector<string> v = { "9.8.17.5295", "9.13.0.0",
                          "12.3.9.1017", "25.3.6.1" };
```

What's the best way to sort them in C++?  The problem here is, of course, that we cannot just sort them lexicographically, but we have to split each string into components and compare those components numerically.  In Python it can be done like this:

```
v.sort(key=lambda x : tuple(map( int, x.split('.'))))
```

But how to do this in C++?  Whatever I can come up with looks rather cumbersome as compared to this one-liner.  The best I found so far is this:

```
array<int, 4> splitversion( const string& s )
{
    array<int, 4> z;
    sscanf( s.c_str(), "%d.%d.%d.%d", &z[0], &z[1], &z[2], &z[3] );
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v = { "9.8.17.5295", "25.3.6.1", "9.13.0.0", "12.3.9.1017" };
    sort( v.begin(), v.end(), []( string s1, string s2 )
          { return splitversion( s1 ) < splitversion(  s2 ); } );
}
```

Of course, sscanf is being frowned upon by C++ people, so I may have to replace it by something else, but as far as I can tell then it gets even more cumbersome.
How would you do this?

Comment: Does `<` work on `std::array` in the way you expect (giving precedence to the first element, etc)?

Comment: I surely expect it does.  The compiler did not complain, so this operator exists, and what other way could it work?

Comment: It might be implemented as a0 < b0 && a1 <b1 && a2 < b2 && ...

Comment: Why is `sscanf` frowned upon? It is simple to use, and in your case there is no possiblily of buffer oveflow that is common in C-style I/O.

Comment: According to cppreference, the operator < on `std::array` is lexicographical comparison as needed here.

Comment: @CR: Yes, I just found that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one will frown :)
This looks a decent solution.
A faster solution would be to hash each element and sort according to the hashes.
An example hash would be:

```
array<int, 4> z;
sscanf( s.c_str(), "%d.%d.%d.%d", &z[0], &z[1], &z[2], &z[3] );
unsigned long long hash = (z[0] << 24) +  (z[1] << 16) +  (z[2] << 8) + z[3];
```

going over the original array/vector and sorting according to the hash values will be significantly faster on long vectors.
This will require more code.
As for minimal code, your is very nice. You can use lambda functions but they are less readable.

Comment: Um, sorting hashes doesn't sort the original values. Your version will sort `1.0.1.0` before `1.0.0.32768`.

Comment: @egur, Thanks, I'll keep that in mind if there are performance issues.  I've got a couple of thousands in my lists.  And Raymond is right, all shifts must be twice as big, long long is 64 bits after all.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do the same, except

```
char c;
istringstream(s) >> z[0] >> c >> z[1] >> c >> z[2] >> c >> z[3];
```

Though, all that streams are quite slow, so you'd better use something like `boost::spirit` in case you have lots of version numbers or at least prepare data in `vector<pair<array<int, 4>, string>>` before sorting.